# Beautiful Soup not altering the object to lower

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So the error that I'm getting is:

**'NoneType' Object has no attribute 'lower'**

The problem is, it was working before I created the second method, but now it is being temperamental. I've just started using pycharm so am very new to the scene

Here's my code:

```
import requests
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import operator

def start(url):
    word_list = []
    source_code = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, 'html.parser')
    for post_text in soup.find_all('p'):
        content = post_text.string
        words = content.lower().split()
        for word in words:
            word_list.append(word)
    clean_up_list(word_list)

def clean_up_list(word_list):
    clean_word_list = []
    for word in word_list:
        accepted = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\'"
        for c in list(word):
            if c not in list(accepted):
                word = word.replace(c, "")
        if len(word) > 0:
            print(word)
            clean_up_list().append(word)


start('http://www.nameofwebsite.com/')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `post_text.string` had no text attributes

That is one of the `p` tag had no text in it. So it returned `None`.

So when you are doing `words = content.lower().split()` you are actually trying to apply `.lower() on None which does not have a .lower attribute`

What you could do is add a `if statement`

**Modification :**

```
for post_text in soup.find_all('p'):
    content = post_text.string
    if content is None: #  Checking if content is None
         continue
    words = content.lower().split()
```

Comment: @user3667111 continue will just skip that particular `p tag` to be more specify that particular iteration

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that will cause your error:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(
    '<p><div>hello</div><div>world</div></p>',
    'html.parser'
)

for p in soup.find_all('p'):
    print(repr(p.string))

--output:--
None
```

From the BeautifulSoup [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string):

> **.string**
>   If a tag has ***only one child***, and that child is a NavigableString, 
>   the child is made available as .string

You could use `get_text()`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(
    '<p><div>hello</div><div>world</div>',
    'html.parser'
)

for p in soup.find_all('p'):
    print(p.get_text())

--output:--
helloworld
```

Or `.strings`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(
    '<p><div>hello</div><div>world</div></p>',
    'html.parser'
)

for p in soup.find_all('p'):
    for string in p.strings:
        print(string)

--output:--
hello 
world
```

But `.strings` also returns whitespace(spaces, tabs, newlines):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(
'''
<p> <---newline there (plus spaces or tab at start of next line)
  <div>hello</div> <--newline there (plus spaces or tab at start of next line)
  <div>world</div> <--newline there
</p>
''',

    'html.parser'
)

for p in soup.find_all('p'):
    for string in p.strings:
        print(string)

--output:--


hello


world
```

To skip the whitespace, you can use `.stripped_strings`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(
'''
<p>
  <div>hello</div>
  <div>world</div>
</p>
''',

    'html.parser'
)

for p in soup.find_all('p'):
    for string in p.stripped_strings:
        print(string)

--output:--
hello
world
```